# c++ Set insertion numbers check for duplicates

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, set

My assignment was to write a set class. 
First i have a node class which has the function

```
void list_head_insert(node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& entry)
{
    head_ptr = new node<Item>(entry, head_ptr);
}
```

this inserts a node at the beginning

I have two set functions, the first one checks to see if the number inserted exist. If it does it returns true if it does not it returns false.

```
template <class Item>
bool set<Item>::contains(const Item& target)
{
   while(head_ptr->data()!=target&&head_ptr->link()!=NULL)
      head_ptr=head_ptr->link();

    if(head_ptr->data()==target)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The second set function inserts the node using the `list_head_insert` function

```
template <class Item>
void set<Item>::insert(const Item& entry)
   // Library facilities used: node2.h
{
    if(contains(entry) !=true)
    {
        list_head_insert(head_ptr, entry);//inserts node
        ++many_nodes;//increases the number of items
    }
}
```

Lastly I have a print function

```
 void print(set<int>bagints)
 {
    for(bag<int>::iterator cursor = bagints.begin(); cursor != bagints.end();   ++cursor)
    {
        cout<<*cursor<< " ";
    }
}
```

When I insert a list of number example `Mylist.insert(10)`...etc and try to print the numbers it does not print them out. I have check the contains function and it works correctly. I think the problem is in the insert but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Advice -- Don't name your class `set`, as C++ has a `std::set` class.

Comment: Cool thanks ill keep that in mind @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, your new set is empty.  When you try to insert the first element, your code will check if it already exists, by invoking `set<Item>::contains()`.

At this moment, `head_ptr` is still `NULL`, (assuming that you have properly initialized it when constructing your empty set). In the while condition of  `set<Item>::contains()` you unfortunately dereference a NULL pointer by doing `head_ptr->data()`.  This is undefined behaviour:

- In best case your code gets a segfault and your code will not do anything else.  And not print anything!
- In other cases, your function might end up returning anything, including true, making your code believe that there is nothing to insert.

Note also that if you would manage to insert anything at all in your set, the next time you'd call `contain()`, you woud change `head_ptr` to point to the last node...

Rewrite your function `set<Item>::contains()`:

```
{
for (auto p=head_ptr; p; p = p->link() ) 
    if(p->data()==target)
    {
        return true;
    }
return false; 
}
```

Comment: I love you man Thanks ^_^  ive been looking at the code for an hour but you know what they say others can see the mistakes you havent LOL.